# How to tokenize/encrypt fields in django?

Tags: django-rest-framework

In the following screenshot the actual password look like `Password123` but when I run

```
user = User.objects.create(...)
user.set_password('Password123')
user.save()
```

```
#then in login I have to run 
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
user....
```

However, Django will automatically set it like this handle the encryption or the tokenization whatever you name this, and the parsing in `authenticate` function.
[image]

- **The question:** I want to do the same for an integer field in order to prevent even the admin from seeing that field so it will be a secret fied only the user can see.

Comment: Sorry, but what's "necroption"? The password is not tokenized, it is hashed. In `authenticate` it's not parsed, but the input is hashed and it's compared with the previously-saved hash. It's OT, but it's important to use the proper terms.

Comment: so based on your follow-up comment, you dont want to do the same thing as it's done with password. Can you describe what are you trying to achieve? Not "encrypt and decrypt this field", but what is the use-case for this.

Comment: prevent the admin from seeing that field so it will be a secret fied only the user can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect what `user.set_password()` does with the parameter value  internally, and do the same for the number in question. You can do it either in model's `save()` method, or preferably in form's `clean_<field>()` method

```
# the form where user submits data
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm): # works even with forms.Form

    def clean_secret_number(self):
        """assuming the field name is called `secret_number`"""
        value = self.cleaned_data.get('secret_number')
        if not value:
            # no value got submitted, return early
            return value
        
        # do the same thing which happens in `user.set_password()`
        value = make_password(value)
        # return the hashed value from form
        return value
```

note it's important to keep the form's field empty when displaying the form with existing data, otherwise it would hash the already-hashed value again when the form is submitted.

Comment: I think OP wants to _encrypt_ (which can be decrypted) the fields value `make_password` on the other hand _hashes_ the value (one way).

Comment: he says "I want to do the same for an integer field" where by "same" he refers to password field which is hashed, but then he talks about tokenization which is something else? If it would be encrypting/decrypting the value, then the admin could do the same no?

Comment: "_in order to prevent even the admin from seeing that field_" - Hashing will do that. "_so it will be a secret fied only the user can see_" - Hashing will not do that (Since it is one way, the data cannot be recovered). If the _admin_ is supposed to encrypt / decrypt the stuff then what stops him from viewing?

Comment: I am using django rest framework (`DRF`) so I can't use forms

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko
so I have to do something like this `SecretCode.objects.create(code= make_password(orignal_code))` then I need to get back the secret code like this `SecretCode.objects.filter(code= orignal_code).first()`. So, for sure this will not return to me my SecretCode that I just created. Should I parse it or somethings